# Redefinition Error In Unity Shader file. What needs to be done? Appropriate syntax please

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

So I'm trying to add a gameObject that accesses Shaders; I'm using Unity 2021.1
The shaders are all custom method and whenever I try to compile the scene; An error pops saying:

> Shader error in 'Hidden/Post FX/Screen Space Reflection': redefinition of '_CameraDepthTexture' at line 31 (on d3d11)

[Here's the link to my shader file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HuPFmD01jObrlQ1BUdhSsKxC3hgIRFZY/view?usp=sharing)